# "SheetrockError: Request failed" but no further detail

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-sheets, sheetrock

I have been using the same sheetrock code for a while now to query my google spreadsheets. (Different spreadsheets on various sites, etc.) For some reason that I am unsure of this time, I get a callback error "SheetrockError: Request failed". Not sure what I am doing wrong.

I've tried searching around on stack overflow and the [Sheetrock Github Repo](https://github.com/chriszarate/sheetrock) and even opened an issue there to no response.

Here is my JS code:

```
var mySpreadsheet = 'https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/e/2PACX-1vSkcN_ec394URPCLiZ5R5YD3qTS65Q9oUken30dhFhm_rLVYftuFc9h9DPuWqtrgz1m27zVVVuEOfQE/pubhtml?gid=585428784';
var bandsTemplate = Handlebars.compile($('#bands-template').html());

function loadResults() {
  $('#bands').sheetrock({
    url: mySpreadsheet,
    query: "select A,B,C,D,E,F,G order by A asc",
    rowTemplate: bandsTemplate,
    callback: function(error, options, response) {
      if (!error) {
        $('#bands').tablesorter();
      }
      else {
        console.log(error);
      }
    }
  });
}

loadResults();
```

Here is my HTML code:

```
<div class="table-responsive">
            <table id="bands" class="table tablesorter">
              <thead>
                <tr>
                  <th class="col-xs-1">Song<br>Name <i class="fa fa-sort fa-fw" aria-hidden="true"></i></th>
                  <th>Band <i class="fa fa-sort fa-fw" aria-hidden="true"></i></th>
                  <th>Arranger <i class="fa fa-sort fa-fw" aria-hidden="true"></i></th>
                  <th>Date <i class="fa fa-sort fa-fw" aria-hidden="true"></i></th>
                  <th>YouTube Link <i class="fa fa-sort fa-fw" aria-hidden="true"></i></th>
                  <th>Notes <i class="fa fa-sort fa-fw" aria-hidden="true"></i></th>
                </tr>
              </thead>
              <script id="bands-template" type="text/x-handlebars-template">
                {{#if num}}
                  <tr>
                    <td><a href="{{cellsArray.[7]}}">{{cellsArray.[0]}}</a></td>
                    <td>{{cellsArray.[1]}}</td>
                    <td>{{cellsArray.[2]}}</td>
                    <td>{{cellsArray.[3]}}</td>
                    <td><a href="{{cellsArray.[4]}}">{{cellsArray.[4]}}</a></td>
                    <td>{{cellsArray.[8]}}</td>
                  </tr>
                {{/if}}
              </script>
            </table>
          </div>
```

I've also set my code up in a [JS Fiddle link](https://jsfiddle.net/z16ujxno/2/) for easy previewing (with the Sheetrock and jQuery plugins already linked in).

My expected result is to have the sheetrock plugin successfully call the spreadsheet using the code provided.

Safari also gives these two errors:

```
[Error] Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 () (tq, line 0)
[Error] Refused to execute https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/e/gviz/tq?gid=585428784&tq=select%20A%2CB%2CC%2CD%2CE%2CF%2CG%20order%20by%20A%20asc&tqx=responseHandler:_sheetrock_callback_0 as script because "X-Content-Type: nosniff" was given and its Content-Type is not a script MIME type.
```

Comment: Seems your link is not standard Google Sheet. Maybe Google refusing SheetRock intentionally in this case

Comment: The spreadsheet link worse fine for me. And it is the same format that SheetRock always uses.

Comment: "_The spreadsheet link worse fine for me_". No, otherwise your jsfiddle would work. **Your spreadsheet reference is wrong**. Sheetrock Example2:  `https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1qT1LyvoAcb0HTsi2rHBltBVpUBumAUzT__rhMvrz5Rk/edit#gid=0` = **a simple shared file**. Your jsfiddle:  `https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/e/2PACX-1vSkcN_ec394URPCLiZ5R5YD3qTS65Q9oUken30dhFhm_rLVYftuFc9h9DPuWqtrgz1m27zVVVuEOfQE/pubhtml?gid=585428784` = **Publish to the web**. Documentation: ["the Sheet must be public."](http://chriszarate.github.io/sheetrock/#basic)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The OP's code is adequate with just two exceptions:

**Sharing**: The OP spreadsheet has not been shared publicly in the form required by the documentation.

The OP used Publish to the Web, but the Sheetrock documentation explains ["Click “Share” and set visibility to “Anyone with the link” or “Public on the web.” Make sure you include the #gid=X portion of the URL; it identifies the specific worksheet you want to use.](http://chriszarate.github.io/sheetrock/#basic)

The spreadsheet link should look something like this:

> `https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1lJSFqDWzLyiYl4rUOe_mm0NJ6yvtwj8lFIihkuwH4VA/edit#gid=0`

**Column of Numerical Data**: [Sheetrock.js seems to need at least one column of numerical data.](https://github.com/chriszarate/sheetrock/issues/136#issuecomment-357076954) This is not specifically mentioned in the documentation, but it is discussed in the outstanding issues. Without the column of numbers, sheetrock will not include all of the rows of data.

This is the view of my spreadsheet:
    [image: Spreadsheet showing column of numbers]

This jsfiddle uses only a few entries from the OP's list, but it demonstrates the display of the table, and the also the operating of the table sorter.

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Tedinoz/o9ndckxb/33/)